# What is the meaning of would here

Tags: meaning, word-usage, modal-verbs

> The Queen of England is very popular and is loved and respected by her
>   subjects.
>
> This sentence is too factual. It sounds like every single of her
>   subjects loves and respects her. Probably there are some people who
>   don’t love and respect her and she might not be popular with everyone.
>   A better sentence **WOULD** be one using tentative language, for example:
>
> The Queen of England appears to be very popular and seems to be loved
>   and respected by many of her subjects.

Could someone explain how "would" work in the above sentence? And what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

*If we were using tentative language*, we *would* be able to construct a better sentence than the factual one.

Here *would* is used because the use of a different formulation is merely a suggestion, a possibility. It *would* be good to write it that way, but maybe the phrase that will finally be printed in the newspaper is the first one.